# Bound Conditional predicate blocks child thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

I am trying to create a thread that gets notified via the Conditional variable to execute some code. I bounded the thread to a class member function like this:

```
m_dbSaver = std::thread(std::bind(&ContactLearningApp::DBWorkerThread, this));
m_lk = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_mutex);
m_Processed = true;
```

Every half a second, I try to run the thread like this:

```
if (m_sampleClock.getTimeMilliseconds() > 500) {
        printf("Save samples to DB\n");
        // Wait for worker to finish processing
        m_cv.wait(m_lk, [this] {return this->m_Processed; });
        // Instruct thread to execute
        m_Ready = true;
        m_cv.notify_one();
        m_sampleClock.reset();
}
```

My Worker thread looksl ike this:

```
void ContactLearningApp::DBWorkerThread() {

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m_mutex);
    printf("Start worker thread. \n");
    while (true) {
        printf("Inside while loop and waiting. \n");
        m_cv.wait(ul, [this] {return this->m_Ready; });
        printf("Condition passed. \n");
        m_Processed = false;
        std::cout << "Worker thread processing data. " << std::endl;
        m_Processed = true;
        ul.unlock();
        m_cv.notify_one();
    }

}
```

The worker thread never passes the condition even though I set the m_Ready predicate to be true. If I set the m_Ready variable to be true before I create the thread, the condition passes. Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time through the worker loop you have the lock, the 2nd time you don't have the lock.

> Wait until notified
>
> The execution of the current thread (which shall
> have locked lck's mutex) is blocked until notified.

It needs to be locked.

```
printf("Start worker thread. \n");
while (true) {
    printf("Inside while loop and waiting. \n");
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m_mutex);
    m_cv.wait(ul, [this] {return this->m_Ready; });
    printf("Condition passed. \n");
    m_Processed = false;
    std::cout << "Worker thread processing data. " << std::endl;
    m_Processed = true;
    ul.unlock();
    m_cv.notify_one();
}
```

This should improve you chance of getting it right.

Comment: So remove the ul.unlock() statement? This way it will have the lock and then release it on the wait statement?

Comment: @terminix00, no see where i moved the lock.